# Need to update my eclipse to run php files on wamp server

Tags: php, eclipse

I have been using eclipse Kepler on my system. I have installed PDT plugin from https://eclipse.org/pdt . I have WAMP on my system. Now what I require is to configure a sample project for the PHP to run on my WAMP server through eclipse.

Comment: Provide your solution or something you tried, please

Comment: I have installed the plugin and have placed the project SamplePHP in www folder of wamp. But I am not able to run that project from eclipse. I am not also seeing the server in my server tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the (localhost)server files from android from **http://10.0.2.2** this work as **local host** for the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Since www is the wamp public folder where you should store your website, perhaps a good idea would be making the workspace the same folder.

To change the workspace in Eclipse just go to File > Switch workspace and select the www folder from wamp, also move your php project there.

You can get rid of all the default files that come inside the www folder if you haven't.

Then  just run on your browser localhost (or do that thru wamp) to see your website folder listed there, then just open it select the php file you want to open (if there is a index.php inside the folder it should open instantly after opening the folder) and it should work.